# Does cassandra lucene index work with vnode? say num_tokens =256

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-lucene-index

I heard it's not a good practice to enable vnode if using cassandra lucene index. Is it still true? I'm using apache cassandra 3.0.5 and matching stratio lucene indexer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.0.5/doc/documentation.rst#disable-virtual-nodes) it is still true.